# Weird matTooltip behavior with toolbar-button and nested button

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular6

I am experiencing an odd behavior - though perhaps it works as intended (which is the reason why I am not filing a bug right away) or I am using `mat-menu-item`-directive in a place I should not?

**When I have a button, which opens a menu, which in turns contains a button with the `mat-menu-item`-directive, its tooltip seems oddly misplaced.**

Using the `mat-button`-directive instead seems to fix the problem, but the button behavior is not the same.

*StackBlitz:* https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inhkax

If you click on profile, you will see, that the "Edit profile" tooltip seems to appear right on the button, that just opened the menu, even though the tooltip belongs to the second button (out of three) inside the menu.

It's always the tooltip of the **first nested button having `mat-menu-item`-directive**, that is shown on the caller-button (in this case "profile") and thus in the wrong place.

It causes this tooltip to "*hang*" until this particular nested button is hovered over, making the misplaced tooltip disappear and causing that same tooltip to appear at the correct specified (or default) position.

You can find out the packages and their versions in the StackBlitz-link.

Comment: Why don't you just use the attribute `matTooltipPosition`. So, in your case, I would use `right` `matTooltipPosition="right"`. I have been testing it with your code and it works fine.

Comment: @k.vincent : what do you mean? I would like the "profile"-button to not display any tooltip while the other tooltips are supposed to be displayed with the default setting, namely `matTooltipPosition="below"`. Why would I want to change the position and why would I even have to?

Comment: Ok, I understood that the toolTip are overlapping the next navi-menu which is actually the case, and that's what you want to prevent. But  anyway I would add position right or after, cause the way how it is now, it's really a bad UX. 1. doesn't look good, 2. It confusing the user. In the other hand, I don't mind if you keep it. It's your issue!

Comment: @k.vincent: you are right. I do not want to keep it as "broken" as it looks in my StackBlitz, which is why I was wondering if I did something wrong (e.g. using wrong directives or something), but apparently (according to Faisal, answer below) it seems like a bug and he also offered a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with Material Menu overlapping. My guess is that while the menu is opening, the mouse is over the first item and hence the tooltip is wrongly displayed. You can avoid this by doing the following:

Add a reference for **`mat-menu-trigger`** e.g.

```
<button mat-button 
        #profileMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" 
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="profile">
    <mat-icon>face</mat-icon>&nbsp;Profile
</button>
```

after that, set **`matTooltipDisabled`** input based on the trigger state on the first menu item like this:

```
<button mat-menu-item 
        matTooltip="Show file upload" 
        [matTooltipDisabled]="!profileMenuTrigger.menuOpen">
    <mat-icon>file_upload</mat-icon>File upload
</button>
```

Link to updated [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bulfx?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Thank you! This sounds like a good workaround, but I believe this is not supposed to happen? Or is it? Meaning: should I open an issue in this regard on github?

Comment: @Igor Yes, I would suggest you to open an issue on github as well. Until then you can use this solution.

Comment: thank you very much! I have tried your solution and it works perfectly. I also filed a bug at the angular/material2-project: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11600. Thank you for the workaround as well!